# Pentaho - Change setting in 'Feature List' for 'IBM DB2 '

Tags: jdbc, db2, pentaho, db2-luw

When you create new conection in pentaho for 'IBM DB2', 'Native (JDBC)'.
The 'Feature List' has default setting for 'SQL: truncate table' as 'ALTER TABLE "TABLE" ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY WITH EMPTY TABLE'
how can I change it to 'TRUNCATE TABLE "TABLE"

Reason for this is that in new databese I do not have permission to deactivate logging.
Error:
Couldn't execute SQL: ALTER TABLE TEST.XXX ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY WITH EMPTY TABLE
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-628, SQLSTATE=42613, SQLERRMC=ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY, DRIVER=3.61.75

I tried changing setting but it doesn't save. Looked for it in files but couldn't find it.

Versions: Db2-LUW v11.5.8.0.    Pentaho version 9.1.

Comment: Which version and flavour of pentaho? Note you are using an antique jdbc driver which is a mistake. Your jdbc driver is v9.7fp3a (dating from year 2011), and per pentaho docs "If you get undefinably issues: Please check, if you use the correct driver that is shipped with the version from your DB2 server. DB2 is here a little bit pedantic and the client JDBC driver should match the server version."  Note also that the error sqlcode "-628" is not permissions related, but may be Db2-server version related, and your question should mention your Db2-server version also.

Comment: Separately, ask your DB2 dba to check whether the database configuration has `BLOCKNONLOGGED` set to Yes (which disables `not logged initially`) and whether that is intentional, or check it yourself via querying with SQL the administrative view `SYSIBMADM.DBCFG`.  Read the Docs!

Comment: @mao thank you for replying

In SYSIBMADM.DBCFG blocknonlogged is set to 'YES'
as it should be on new security measures.

I will try a new version of JDBC but I don't believe anything will change.
Because I don't believe that will change the PENTAHO preset setting on how to execute the truncate command.

Comment: Please __edit your question__ to specify the Pentaho version, and the Db2-server version and fixpack, and HA status.   Updating the jdbc driver is just required maintenance and you should do this regardless for proper maintenance. `BLOCKNONLOGGED=YES` is __not__ a security matter, it helps  HA. If your database is not highly-available (not using HADR or similar equivalent ) then `BLOCKNONLOGGED=YES` is not necessary.  Depending on your Db2-server version BLOCNONLOGGED=YES will allow `truncate table... immediate`.

Comment: Tried on pentaho 9.1 (originaly 4.4), DB is 'DB2 v11.5.8.0', ODBC the last one I tried is 3.72.54 (last one that uses db2jcc.jar). And yes they need BLOCKNONLOGGED setting for HA. If you run 'truncate table... immediate' it will work. The problem is stil in pentaho that if you use 'Table output' and tick 'Truncate table' pentaho will do this with 'ALTER TABLE "TABLE" ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY WITH EMPTY TABLE' and that feature is the problem for this case. Because I can't find a way to change it.

Comment: I suggest you open a support ticket with the provider of your Pentaho.

Comment: For future reades there seems to be an options for Pentaho to create plugin that could solve this. https://community.hitachivantara.com/question/change-setting-in-feature-list-for-ibm-db2#1c92b975-35b6-4e71-a318-0188533b6c42